# Printing out a stringstream using str() and rdbuf()

Tags: c++

When I have:

```
std::ostringstream oss("Hello");
```

Why does this work:

```
std::cout << oss.str();
```

but this doesn't print anything:

```
std::cout << oss.rdbuf();
```

Reading the definition of `operator<<(std::ostream&, std::streambuf*)` say that it  will print characters from the buffer. Does `oss.rdbuf()` not contain anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is related to the fact that here, `oss` is *ostringstream* object (*ostringstream* is output stream so its destination is to *write to it* and not to *read from it*) and to fact how streams manage its internal buffer.

You can change

```
std::ostringstream oss("Hello");
```

to

```
std::istringstream oss("Hello");  // or std::stringstream oss("Hello");
```

and it will work as expected. Alternatively use

```
std::cout << oss.rdbuf()->str(); // this will print a copy of all buffer content
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::ostringstream oss("Hello");
    std::istringstream oss2("Hello");
    cout << oss.rdbuf()->str() << endl;  // prints "Hello"
    cout << oss2.rdbuf();                // prints "Hello"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @templateboy is there somethinng more you want me to explain?

Answer (score 1):

Objects of ostringstream class use a string buffer that contains a sequence of characters. This sequence of characters can be accessed directly as a string object, using member str. That explains first part.

```
std::ostringstream oss("Hello");
std::cout << oss.str(); // works
```

The rdbuf returns pointer to the associated streambuf object, which is charge of all input/output operations. Thus, you need to use str() again to print the contents as in:

```
std::cout << oss.rdbuf()->str();
```

instead of:

```
std::cout << oss.rdbuf();
```

Comment: But the definition of the operator `operator<<(ostream, streambuf*)` says that it prints out the content held in the buffer. Read the other answer for a reason why it didn't work.